# codeigniter problem - site redirects to localhost after migrating

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

i just copied the CI files from server to my localhost and I am having problem running the site.

Whenever i click the site link in WAMP
http://localhost/CmpOnline/

it shows me the same folderlist as on localhost

this is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|javascript|stylesheets|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in the config file

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/CmpOnline/";

$config['index_page'] = "";

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

I changes this to all the other available options but it still does not work

I tried this 
[.htaccess and codeigniter not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4515122/htaccess-and-codeigniter-not-working)
and this 
[Remove index.php From URL - Codeigniter 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2)

But it still does not work.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `RewriteBase`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /CmpOnline
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|javascript|stylesheets|uploads|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

since the `RewriteRule` is sending everything to the root of `RewriteBase`, which defaults to `/` (CodeIgniter will still need the `base_url` setting, for its internal stuff).

Answer (score 1):

if

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

change it to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

if use this

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

with redirect or header location to url not in htaccess will not work you must add the url in htaccess to work

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Send request via index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Please add some explanation around your answer.