# localhost web moved to godaddy server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have problem with my developed website locally,
After completion of my development i moved my folder from WWW to godaddy server with subdomain,

My application is developed in codeigniter framework,

I changed my base_url and database configuration, but when i load my login controller, it throw 404, page not found error,

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/';
```

i am opening my webpage as

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/login
```

what went wrong? what are steps to take while moving from localhost to webserver?

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095049/codeigniter-problem-site-redirects-to-localhost-after-migrating

Answer (score 0):

You must give the default controller in routes.php file

It located at here

```
./root/application/config/routes.php
```

In this file just change the line

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";  
// give default controller name instead of welcome
```

Good Luck ['}