# Codeigniter - XAMP - htaccess issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, xampp

I've looked a lot of provided solutions in this site and other, but can't seem to find something that works.

I've just downloaded Codeigniter and put it in htdocs folder from Xamp. Changed its name to 'notas'. Changed `notas/config/config.php` the properties like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/notas/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Created a .htaccess file in`'notas'` with many approaches. Currently, I have it like this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /notas/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

and the URL `http://localhost/notas/welcome` returns `Object not found - 404`, where welcome is that default controller in the folder

If I put it like this, I get a 500 error

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

If there is any other data I could provide to help solve it, please, ask for it

Thanks

**EDIT**

If I put the .htaccess file like

```
Satisfy all
```

or

```
Satisfy any
```

Still get 404. I've already rechecked that inside the controller folder exists a Welcome.php file

Comment: Try other htaccess data https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10209010/codeigniter-htaccess-not-working

Comment: Tried all the htaccess from the post. The only one that changed from 404 to 500 was Ak memon

Comment: try to config your index_page `$config['index_page'] = ''` to point your index file

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I was the one who broke it in the first place. I changed the name of /notas/index.php file thinking it was like an example and wanted to see something different. After renaming it correctly and putting the following htaccess worked

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Thanks for the help. Thanks specially to Amit Sharma that made me realize this

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess it should be something like this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Base URL should be like this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/notas/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Still getting 404 with that htaccess. If I'm not mistaken, the config is the same as I put in the post,

Comment: Yes, it works. Putting localhost/notas/ redirects to the same page

Comment: in the first htacces that you mentioned it should be RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic baseurl like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] .= preg_replace('@/+$@','', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

And in htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And don't forget to set `$config['index_page'] = 'index';` to `$config['index_page'] = '';` in config.php