# .htaccess CodeIgniter implementation

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess

I came across this code for .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is suppose to remove `index.php` from the link.

I have created the file under the view directory, however it doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515153/1933845

Comment: You have to set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php` for starters. That with your .htaccess should work.

Answer (score 0):

The *.htaccess* file should be in the root of your project, alonside the main `index.php` file. Example of directory structure and location of *.htaccess* (assumes that you haven't moved the location of you application or system directory):

```
 -public_html
    -index.php
    -.htaccess
    -application
    -system
```

In `application/config/config.php`, *index.php* should be removed from the `index_page` config:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

You may also have to change the value of the `uri_protocol` config:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI'; //(If this value doesn't work, try the others!)
```