# Routing in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want all URI to route to default_controller/(:any)

for example if the url looks like this : www.anypage.com

I want www.anypage.com/test_segment to route to www.anypage.com still where I will read Segment 1 to customize my site

the reason why I am doing this is to avoid doing something ugly like www.anypage.com?s=test_segment

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Between the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1397032/582278) you should have everything you need. There are lots of other answers on StackOverflow covering this topic as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like `$route['404_override'] = 'default_controler/lookup_method';` in `application/config/routes.php`