# default routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm exploring codeigniter. On app startup default controller is changed to load my controller.

Controller properly loads the view and that's fine, so I'm guessing routing works as expected, but when I use (manually type on address bar other method on same controller) same url pattern /controller/method I'm getting 404 error, either view exist.

Do  have to change some default routing behavior or something else is problem?

Thanks

Comment: You might need an htaccess file. Google for a CodeIgniter htaccess file.

Comment: @user1765862 : you have to use index.php/controller/method/id  unless u use .htaccess to rewrite url . very easy put .htaccess file in docs root ,content of .htaccess can be find in codeigniter user guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if you already removed index.php from your url pattern, assuming that's the case you should type inside browser address field `index.php/controller/method`. (if you manually type url as you describe)

If you on the other hand do not want to use index.php on every link you can consider to remove that, [more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397014/how-do-i-write-a-htaccess-file-to-make-codeigniters-url-routing-work/1397032#1397032).

Answer (score 0):

Well this may be the because of **index.php** file as mentioned above or else if you would like get rid of index.php Kindly include .htaccess file in your application.

```
 config/config.php - modifiy 
 $config['base_url'] = 'index.php'
 $config['base_url'] = '' // set it to blank
```

For .htaccess file refer the below code

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

*follow this*

> **root_folder/.htaccess**
>
> *to remove `index.php` in url*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

---

> *set base URL*
>
> **root_folder/application/config/config.php**

```
| to $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] if available, or localhost otherwise.
| The auto-detection mechanism exists only for convenience during
| development and MUST NOT be used in production!
|
| If you need to allow multiple domains, remember that this file is still
| a PHP script and you can easily do that on your own.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = 'http://[::1]/my-project/';
```

---

> *removing `index.php` in url, even on request post in form*
>
> **root_folder/application/config/config.php**

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

---

> s*et default controller, mine is 'home'*
>
> **root_folder/application/config/routes.php**

```
| controller and method URI segments.
|
| Examples: my-controller/index -> my_controller/index
|       my-controller/my-method -> my_controller/my_method
*/
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

---

> *after that, make sure that the all controller file name is capitalize.*
>   a*lso a class name.*
>
> *this is also important mostly when you need to upload in a live*
>   *server.*
>
> **root_folder/application/controllers/Home.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * 
 * 
 * @author Lloric Garcia <emorickfighter@gmail.com>
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends MY_Controller {

    public function index() {

    }    

}
```

---

> *then this will be you url*
>
> `http://[::1]/my-project/home`

---

> *that is my set up even in live server*
>
> *all of this came from*

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/index.html