# Codeigniter Installation Moved

Tags: php, codeigniter

I recently moved my codeigniter application from a subdomain to operate under my domain.

Basically I moved it from:

```
https://account.mywebsitehere.com
```

To:

```
https://mywebsitehere.com/account
```

Now when I try to access anything like `/invoices` it removes the `/account` from the url and results in a not found page. I have changed the base url in the config file but it is still resulting in this error.

Other than going through the entire application and changing every link to be `/account/...` How can I make the application work under the `/account` in the url?

My `.htaccess` file located at `public_html/panda/.htaccess` is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1    
!^(index\.php|robots\.txt|files\/images|files\/css|files\/js|files\/swf|files\/upload)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mywebsitehere.com/panda/$1 [R,L]\
```

Comment: I may be off on this, but I suppose you could edit the htaccess to make the new path as the default one.

Comment: @AndrewP. Please explain further.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397014/how-do-i-write-a-htaccess-file-to-make-codeigniters-url-routing-work) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put that code in .htaccess file and try it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /account/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|js|uploads|css|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It still dumps the /account/ when I visit /invoices

Comment: change $config['base_url']=" "; if it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `base_url` to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://mywebsitehere.com/account';
```

Comment: @user3968645 Please update question with .htaccess file (hidden file)

Answer (score 0):

first, upload an image to the root directory and see if you can access it within the browser.
if you cant access it , check your server's configuration and your .htaccess file.

Comment: can you print the screen ?